# inviting people to answer questions

Tags: support, feature-request

Suppose I have a question and I am in dire need for the answer to that question . Let's say that question fails to attract answers or attentions. But there are some users who I believe can answer that question . Is there any way by which I can request them to post an answer ?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1159/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4929/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6190/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This is rather a bit gawky. But frankly, I've been accustomed often to such. First, approach the user you want to, at first, comment on your question. Then, if all goes right, you can request earnestly to post an answer. But, you can't impose on him the duty to post an ans. Rather you can only request. But first, ask for at least a comment.